# How can I render geometry represented in a 64-bit floating point environment?

Tags: gpu, floating-point, space-partitioning, open-world, precision

In [this video about Star Citizen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTGJOC0stus&t=12m30s), right at the 12:30 mark on the timeline you can see the player zooming in on a space station who's location is clearly out of the limit of 32-bit floating point numbers. As I understand it, in this game they're using 64-bit floating point precision for location calculations.

I'd like to implement something similar: an environment where objects are represented with 64-bit floating point precision, but which can still be rendered on 32-bit GPUs.

I do not understand how Star Citizen is able to render it in correct proportion with 32-bit GPUs since I've read that most GPUs run like 3x slower in double precision mode.

In other words how should I pass vertex positions and other rendering data accurately to the underlying rendering hardware? What should I do to the data to render it in 32 bit space? Or should I just use double precision GPUs?